# Is there any replacement for ethyl mercaptan in LPG?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, smell, organosulfur-compounds

**Ethanethiol**, commonly known as **ethyl mercaptan**, is a colorless gas added to **LPG** in order to detect its leakage.

Apart from ethyl mercaptan, is there any gas or liquid that may be used as a replacement to this?

Comment: Methyl mercaptan is also used as an oderant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would one want to replace it?

The choice of ethanethiol is a reasonable compromise between its toxicity and the extremely low detection limit around 1 ppb (1mg/1000 kg).

Comment: I guess they don't like the smell.

Comment: it's also worth mentioning that thiols are preferred over amines, to which human noses are also extremely sensitive, because humans desensitize to amines much more quickly than thiols.